# appending child div to each div with for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I want to append child div to each given parent divs. The child div supposed to be decorated by calling decorateDiv().

For example, after the appendChildren is executed, following divs
        
          
          
        
should take the following form (assuming decorateDiv does nothing)

```
function appendChildren() 
{
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) 
  {
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   decorateDiv(newDiv);
   allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

// Mock of decorateDiv function for testing purposes
function decorateDiv(div) {}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to return the decorated div like `newDiv = decorateDiv(newDiv);` then in your `decorateDiv()` method return `newDiv`

Comment: He doesn't need to, elements are live nodes. Modifications made within decorateDiv apply to the element even if it isn't returned.

Answer (score 10):

You're running into the fact that `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a **live** NodeList. That means that the new `<div>` elements that you're adding to the page become part of the list as soon as you do so.

What you can do is turn that NodeList into a plain array beforehand:

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
allDivs = [].slice.call(allDivs, 0);
```

Now using "allDivs" in the loop will just append your new elements into the ones that were there when you originally went looking for them.

Comment: Good find. That explains why chrome crashed when I tested the code, it's a recursive loop.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `allDivs.length` in the `condition` field will accesses the `length` property each time the loop iterates. So declare a variable for the `length` outside the function and specify the variable name in the `condition` field.

```
function appendChildren() 
{
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var len = allDivs.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len ; i++) 
  {
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   decorateDiv(newDiv);
   allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

// Mock of decorateDiv function for testing purposes
function decorateDiv(div) {}
```

Comment: ....right. I always cache the length out of good practice so it doesn't have to re calculate the length each time. This is tricky. Are there any other 'getElementBy' or QSA that have this same deal? Having 'live' lists?

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByTagName` returns **Live `NodeList`**, which keeps the length increasing for every new div added.

Either use `document.querySelectorAll()` which is **Not a Live `NodeList`**.

```
let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
```

or Convert the Live NodeList to array. With ES6 [...spread] operator its really simple.

```
let allDivs = [...document.getElementsByTagName("div")];
```